# Symfony 4 imported .yaml services are autowiring

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, autowired, monolog

services.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: commands.yaml }

parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true     
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false       

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Service\ExampleService:
        arguments:
            - '%env(URL)%'
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

commands.yaml

```
parameters:

services:

    App\Command\Import\ExampleCommand:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Service\ExampleService'
            - '@monolog.logger.example'
            - '@parameter_bag'
```

When i run `ExampleCommand` monolog instance is default with default channel. I think the reason why ExampleCommand get diffrent logger is autowiring. When i comment `- { resource: commands.yaml }` command run without errors. I have manny services and I need divided configuration.

Everything is properly without import:

services.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: commands.yaml }

parameters:

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true     
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false       

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Service\ExampleService:
        arguments:
            - '%env(URL)%'
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'  

    App\Command\Import\ExampleCommand:
        arguments:
            - '@App\Service\ExampleService'
            - '@monolog.logger.example'
            - '@parameter_bag'
```

Is there way with many imported .yaml?

Comment: You need the _defaults section repeated in each service yaml file.  Also, any files under config/services will automatically be loaded eliminating the need to use the imports section.  And yes the Command directory needs to be excluded.  Better yet, if you do plan on dividing things up then just get rid of the master App\: section all together.